# Whe button continueButton isnt working? It should start the new Activity if I have a text in EditText or make a Toast

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I work with a program which should make parameters for character. A person writes a name then generate force and health by clicking the button. After all, he click the continueButton which should start the MainActivity if name exists or make a Toast text. But it's not working. The problem should be in the end of onClick method.

There is a code

```
public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener {
 final Random random = new Random();

String toastText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
    Button getData = findViewById(R.id.getData);

    final EditText newName = findViewById(R.id.newName);
    TextView newHealth = findViewById(R.id.newHealth);
    TextView newForce = findViewById(R.id.newForce);

    continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    getData.setOnClickListener(this);

    newName.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){

                Character.name = newName.getText().toString();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.getData: {
            Character.health = random.nextInt(100);
            newHealth.setText(String.valueOf(Character.health));
            Character.force = random.nextInt(100);
            newForce.setText(String.valueOf(Character.force));
        }

        // THERE IS A PROBLEM
        if (newName.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.continueButton:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    return;
            }
        } else{
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.continueButton:
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your `Button` inside `onCreate` method. Like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements View.OnClickListener { 
    private Button yourButton; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        yourButton= findViewById(R.id.your_button_id); 
        yourButton.setOnClickListener(this); 
    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    { 
        switch (view.getId()) { 
        case R.id.your_button_id: 
            // Do something 
        } 
    } 
}
```